# What are qualities/features that you think about when thinking of a musical "note"? (For AI/programming purposes)

Tags: theory

**TLDR, open-ended: What is a set of qualities that a musical "note" can have that are important when playing or analyzing music?** Think **performance, practice, rehearsal, production**, any setting, but be specific in your answer about **where and why** the quality is useful.

Hey all. Hope this isn't teetering on being inappropriate for this forum. Please cite a bit of the community ruleset if I missed a guideline.

I'm a lifelong musician who's also involved in the the AI/programming community. I'm finding that all programming languages, tools, libraries, etc. don't give me what I want, so I'm taking on making my own simpler but more comprehensive open source Python library for music analysis, info retrieval, AI, DSP, anything you could want from programmatic music.

Well, now I've got to come up with general musical types to program and define them by important qualities. E.g. defining frequencies, pitches, timbres, forms, harmonies, and more, and attaching important properties to them that programmers and working musicians would find crucial.

I want to take a messy comprehensive list of types and features, tighten it up, and port it into simple Python code that anyone can use for music analysis, AI, notation software/file conversion, etc.

**So here's my question.**

Let's start with just a music "note." For you musicians, what are important qualities that can define a "note" and how you think about that note, including relative to other parts of a song, other members of a band/orchestra/choir/group, the harmony of the song, how the human ear perceives that note, and more?

Here's a follow-up question. What's the least that a note needs to be a note? Obviously if music notation notes are notes, they don't need timbres. Does it even need a duration? Does it even need a pitch? When does a note stop being a note?

Perhaps another follow-up. Do you feel like any books or literature answer these questions well enough to be comprehensive, and can you point them my way?

**An incomplete list I've compiled is:**

- Pitch of the note (e.g. tempered tuning pitch, like A4)
- Frequency of the note (especially helpful when doing anything not 12-tone tempered, or N-tone tempered)
- Pitch bends/frequency bends
- Timbre of the note (as well as how the timbre can change, e.g. wavetables)
- Related to timbre, the instrument which plays the note
- Duration of the note (in beats, seconds, etc.)
- When the note starts (and stops) relative to a starting time (arbitrary time 0, start of a song, start of a measure, etc.)
- What the strength/emphasis of the start beat is, or conversely the amount of syncopation, e.g. 1 is obviously a strong beat in a repetitive time signature, while the "ah" of 1 is probably less strong in some contexts and more syncopated.
- Dynamics/loudness (and change in dynamics) of that note
- Articulation of the note
- Misc. expressions (?) that can be notated on that note
- Whether the note is tied to other notes, e.g. in a tuple or in a chord
- What contains the note, e.g. what measure, section, part, piece of music
- Any lyrics on that note
- Anything notation-specific (e.g. where on a staff the note is written, note head shape, etc.)

Assuming this question is appropriate and yields interesting conversation, I might be back to ask more about other musical objects, like chords

Comment: The question is just broad enough that answering it would take a book. Some of these books have already been written, have you read them?

Comment: A lot of the answer depends on which particular instrument  - different ones will use different parameters.

Comment: Are you concentrating on written notes, heard notes, or both? You've already explained that some things aren't required for written notes, such as timbre, but some of the things you've mentioned aren't necessary for heard notes (assuming all we see is Synthesia-style bars for MIDI notes), such as whether notes are tied or even articulations(!).

Comment: I see this is as a programming interface design question. You're defining an interface of some module X, and you want the interface to have a concept of "note". But you haven't yet decided on exactly what it is that X _does_. What is its functionality? When you know what the thing does, then you can decide what would be a meaningful definition of "note" in that interface.

Comment: There are two different questions here: what is a note, and what are the characteristics of a note. Please see the help section for suggestions on asking a good question. In particular, questions "yielding conversation" don't fit well in the SE Q/A format.

Comment: @ojs That's why I asked if you knew of any literature you could refer me to! I see the question has been closed due to lack of focus, but that's the problem--the subject of the question is up to interpretation and needs focusing through discussion. Please let me know if you have references. @ user1079505 I did read the help section, and while questions like these aren't explicitly eschewed, I understand why we wouldn't want to have them in the forum. I don't know where it is reasonable to ask questions like these in musical communities anywhere, but at least I got some answers before closing.

Comment: It's a system design problem. You're designing a system, so define what exactly and concretely it should do. What are its inputs and outputs? Do you want to convert files between existing notation application formats, or just import them, or not even import? What exactly does the system produce as output? Should the system be able to perform written pieces? For what exact purpose is it used for? Can you write use-cases for the system? If not, then you don't really know what you're trying to make.

Comment: Broadly speaking, the questions you're asking have already been solved by technology! MIDI is the most common computer format for serializing sheet music and live-performance musical information. Every note is associated with a whole bag of data about the characteristics of its performance and articulation. MIDI also has provisions for multiple streams of data corresponding to elements like dynamics and tone color that can change over the course of a note's duration. It's an extremely mature, well-defined, and powerful format!

Comment: In fact, I'm voting to reopen because I believe "use MIDI" is the unambiguously correct answer for all of the questions OP brought up. An answer to that effect would be perfectly reasonable and deserves to be written.

Comment: Appreciate the vote of confidence, Kevin! However, MIDI is not the answer I'm looking for. MIDI is great for describing music within a strict and symbolic manner, but fails to describe it in a way human musicians would look at music, and fails to consider a lot of musical structures musicians rely on. Otherwise, MIDI would take off with musicologists as well as producers. Being explicit, I'm thinking MIT's Python library Music21, but easier yet more expressive and powerful to use. However, if you think MIDI is a valuable answer, I invite you to answer if the question reopens!

Comment: Finally, I think I'll just keep these (very helpful) comments in mind but move on. What I wanted was a discussion about the building blocks of a note that we could represented. Yes, this is a long-term project, and I want to go for a lot in this system--arbitrary file type conversion, musicological analysis, composition, AI facilitation, etc. While I know what I want, it doesn't seem like this is the setting to have that abstract conversation on what constitutes a "note" so I can distill that into my system. Probably best I build first and only then ask for concrete feedback. Thank you, all!

Answer (score 1):

Musical notation is, first and foremost, instructions for human performers. One element of that notation is "notes". To know if, when and how to use a note, you need to know how human players will react to those instructions.

The written language of instructions is also used for describing abstract ideas in a music theory context or otherwise without meaning the music to be actually performed like in a concert, but even then, there is an implied idea of a person reading the notation and acting on it. For example, one might try to transcribe sounds of nature like birds singing as musical notation, but the writer must have at least a vague idea of a player with an instrument.

Whether a writer of music wants to use notes or some other forms of instructions, and which qualities the writer considers as important, depends on what the writer wants to achieve. "Make chaotic sounds with your instrument" could be a performance instruction that doesn't use notes, but which would probably end up producing sounds that could be described in terms of notes. Another one could be "slow filter sweep from 50 Hz to 1000 Hz". An instruction "very fast filter sweep from 1000 Hz to 50 Hz" might produce a sound that another person might transcribe as a note.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more clear on what "note" means: A black spot in a staff on a sheet of paper or a single musical event from a rather abstract viewpoint? The connection in between is the main subject literate musicians' life on stage is much about.

You're heading tough time teaching that to machines, or having machines learning it themselves. On that topic of AI and machine learning I, for one, am quite sensible: Once machines have the knowledge, would they manage to teach it to little humans and/or machines? (As a philosophical marginal note: I'm afraid some well-known AI apologetes are eager to suck it out of mankind like vampire-gods, all that knowledge about the bad as well as about the beautiful things humans could think and say and do once, leaving them stupid as plastic dolls, Eloi, and put it all into a black-hole waste bin they dream of, called Singularity.)

You are probably better off sticking to a common set of features to read from musical notes: pitch, duration, and stress. Three features should be enough to get your brain running for a start, admitted that depends on what you already have got and achieved.

Keep in mind that few features are actually encoded in notes. Much is to be interpreted measure-wise (e.g. accidentals applied to every note on the same line till natural sign or end of measure), period-wise (keys) or piece-wise (musical practice of the time a piece was written). And when it comes to phrasing, very much is implied as well. Not to forget the queen of implication in all music: the pause. Hence, one having such a list of features of a note or musical events should count the time-offset among them as well. Or is that exactly what you meant with "where in the staff"? Again I am inclined to read it meant in a graphical sense, given the shape of the notehead you also refer to.

Musical notes are like letters of a word. They need to be read together phrase after phrase.

Developping an ASCII-based notation system myself, with associated a likewise text-specified sound-level translation engine to write actual PCM data into a file, I learned that the dots in a sheet you call notes is not more than about 10% of what defines ("organic" versus synthetic) music. The most defining part is made up from the instrument played and the imagination of sound and groove the human playing expresses, performs.

In the process of "making" I wrote my program so that the levels of properties intellectually interpreted from the sheet are kept separate in memory as long as possible on the various structural levels:

- common properties of every measure;
- measure-specific ones;
- specifics to voices in the measure;
- chord / motif / whatever a bunch of notes at same offset after the beat-one bar;
- finally, the note for length and pitch and specific articulation, much depending on what the sound specification of the associated voice offers in terms of variations accessed by parameters.

Stress, for example, is mostly *not described* as specific to a note, but implied by its offset and the stress pattern defined on the measure level, only manipulated now and then to shape its presence relative to other notes in the harmonic chord stack (i.e. its weight), or special accent at that offset.

Offset and duration, as another example, are both not reigned by a strictly linearly proportional relationship between beats per minute and the nominal note value, because tempo changes in a small percentage range add their spice to musical expression of a performance, and if swing-patterns are involved, the duration of an eighth or sixteenth might differ slightly from the last and the next.

Having covered subtleties of stress and duration, let us complete these regarding pitch: The tuning of notes in a harmonic chord stack could possibly change along the position in the measure, according the current harmony. Depends on the instrument, say, strings vs. brass. Strings, since fretless instruments, are tempered naturally. So, a nominal pitch, mapped 1:1 to a frequency, could be calculated to Hz as soon as possible. For string and other continuous-pitch voices, if you proceed bottom-up, you can resolve pitches not before you know the harmonic context.

That's why you should start focussing on the prevalent three note features listed above. At least if your music is intended not to scream "Look mum, all is computer-generated" to your audience.

Not before it comes to synthesizing and saving the sound of a distinct tone (meaning the actual musical-acoustical event), these properties from the different levels are calculated from abstract-relative units to the single note being processed, to absolute units, and merged into one set.

The trade-off of repeatedly applying same tones regarding the limited time and memory consumption of rendering music the raytracing-like way I do, is enough I think to have musicians reliably guess it is computer-generated music nevertheless, and rightly so. Quantum computing will turn off-line synthesis to a finger's snip opportunity to practice patience meditation, just early enough.